# Unterschiede zwischen "Tadeln", "Schimpfen", "Ausschimpfen" und "Beschimpfen"

Tags: difference, meaning-in-context

Manchmal ist es nicht sehr wichtig, ein exaktes Wort für eine Situation zu benutzen aber wenn man die Agression definieren will, soll man das exakte Wort verwenden um weiter Aggression (und/oder Missverständnisse) zu verhindern.

Die Wörterbucher haben mir nicht weiter geholfen, als ich die Unterschiede zwischen **Schimpfen**, **Ausschimpfen**, **Beschimpfen** und **Tadeln** lernen wollte.

ich stelle die Beispielsätze dar;

Vater sagt seinem Sohn;

> Wenn du es nochmal machst, bekommst du Ärger. (Tadeln?)

der Polizist sagt einem Fahrer;

> Wenn du es nochmal machst, bekommst du Strafe. (Tadeln?)

Der böse Coach sagt seinem Sportler

> Nächstes Mal musst du es schaffen, du Idiot (Schimpfen und Ausschimpfen?)

In einem Kampf, sagt jemand jemandem

> H*rensohn, wenn du hierher nochmal kommst, werde ich dich erstechen
>   (Beschimpfen?)

Z.B in den ersten drei Bespielsätze, es gibt irgendeine Beleidiung, um die Person besser zu machen aber in den letzten Satz gibt es Beleidigung um seine Ärger zu zeigen und den Horror verbreiten.

Habe ich die Unterschiede richtig verstanden und gibt es andere wichtige Wörter zu diesem Thema?

Comment: 1: Drohen, 2. "eine Strafe", sonst Rassismus. Auch hier Drohung. 3. Befehl, 4. Drohung.

Comment: Da Deine Beispiele nicht viel mit den Wörtern, die Du suchst, zu tun haben, schlug ich vor die Frage als "unclear what you asking for" zu schließen. Die Formen mit Schimpfen sind i.d.R. mit erhobener Stimme und Temperament verbunden, da passt ein nüchternes "sagen" nicht. Man weiß aber jetzt nicht, geht es mehr um die Beispiele oder die 4 Wörter. Außerdem erklärst Du nicht, was die Wörterbücher schreiben, und wieso das nicht weiterhilft - so besteht die Gefahr, dass wir das jetzt hier, zu Deinem Verdruß, wiederholen.

Comment: Wofür steht »H * rrensohn«? Soll das *Herrensohn* oder *Hurensohn* heißen? Das erste Wort macht keinen Sinn, das zweite schreibt man aber mit nur einem R. Davon abgesehen sind wir alle hier keine Kinder mehr, und selbst Kinder überleben es unbeschadet, wenn sie mal das Wort *Hurensohn* lesen.

Comment: @user unknown: Ich finde, aus Titel, Fettdruck und Schlusssatz geht relativ klar hervor, worum es in der Frage geht: um die Unterschiede der vier fetten Wörter und um die Frage, ob es in ihrem Bedeutungsbereich weitere gibt, die wichtig wären. So gesehen kreisen die beiden bisherigen Antworten um das Richtige und die Frage muss nicht geschlossen werden.

Comment: @userunknown Du hast eigentlich recht, dass meine Beispiele nicht zu dem Thema passt und Schimpfen sind mit Temperament verbunden. Aber da ich hier nur schriftlich Fragen stellen kann, musste ich die Temperament irgendwie mit den Wörtern definieren.

Comment: @userunknown Die Wörterbücher schreiben immer sehr ähnliche Wörter, wenn man nach schimpfen, ausschimpfen und beschimpfen sucht. z.B die zweite Übersetzung von schimpfen ist die dritte Übersetzung von beschimpfen (oder umgekehrt) und wenn die Bedeutung sehr ähnlich sind, kann man die Wörterbücher nicht benutzen, um die Wörter zu unterscheiden.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast  Herrensohn:D Ja, du hast recht, dass wir nicht mehr Kinder sind aber ich dachte wenn man direkt dieses Schimpfwort schreibt, können manche Leute es beleidigend finden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wie Pollitzer korrekt bemerkt, unterscheidet sich **Schimpfen** von den anderen drei Worten dadurch, dass es nicht unbedingt an eine Person gerichtet sein muss.

Das ist aber nicht der einzige Unterschied.

**Beschimpfen** passt thematisch am wenigsten zu den anderen drei: Es ist -wie Du bereits festgestellt hast- eigentlich immer mit einer Beleidigung oder Drohung verbunden. Es muss keine -gefühlte oder tatsächliche- Untat des beschimpften zugrunde liegen, um jemanden zu beschimpfen.

**Tadeln** ist von den restlichen Worten das schwächste: Man drückt seinen Unmut oder seine Enttäuschung über etwas aus, was der andere getan hat, meist in sachlichem Ton. Der Tadel ist ein umgangssprachlich kaum noch verwendetes Wort, wird aber im professionellen / beruflichen Umfeld oder in der Schule verwendet, um in Akten (z.B. Personalakte, Klassenbuch, Führungszeugnis) Fehler / Fehlverhalten festzuhalten.

**Schimpfen** und **Ausschimpfen** sind in ihrer Intensität sehr ähnlich, wobei man letzteres eigentlich nur in Verbindung mit Jugendlichen / Kindern verwendet (wenn ich einen Erwachsenenen ausschimpfe, dann nehme ich ihn nicht ernst), während ersteres eher für Dinge / Tatsachen verwendet wird.

Mit Erwachsenen *schimpft* man dahingegen eher nicht, man verwendet in diesem Zusammenhang eher Verben wie **zurechtweisen** (eher sachlich) oder **anfahren** (eher wütend).

Comment: Einem Tadel an der Schule, wo er auch umgangssprachlich so verwendet wird, misst man il.d.R. wegen des formalen Charakters ein höheres Gewicht bei, als einem Schimpfen. Beruflich kenne ich das Wort Abmahnung - wird Tadel anders/auch verwendet? Schimpfen und Ausschimpfen ist sicher in vielen Beziehungen ein problematisches Verhalten, als Bezeichnung für dieses Verhalten, und nur darum kann es hier gehen, sind beide angemessen. Ich meine, dass Ausschimpfen immer mit einer gewissen Dauer einhergeht, während Schimpfen auch kurz sein kann.

Comment: @Torsten Link. Vielen Dank für Deine Antwort. Es ist mir jetzt viel klarer. Man konnte die Unterschiene nicht besser erklären.

Answer (score 2):

**Ein Unterschied:** Beim **Ausschimpfen**, **Beschimpfen** und **Tadeln** sind adressierte Personen vonnöten (anwesende oder auch angeschriebene), gegen die sich der Unmut richtet. Beim **Schimpfen** [über das Wetter, rote Ampeln] ist das nicht zwingend erforderlich.

Wer Gelächter verbreiten will, sagt also:

> - das Wetter beschimpfen
> - eine rote Ampel ausschimpfen
> - einen geplatzten Reifen tadeln

Und für die, die mäkeln wollen – ja, auch Tiere kann man ausschimpfen. Bloß nicht schriftlich.

Comment: Vielen dank für Deine Antwort. Der Unterschied, den Du geschrieben hast ist sehr wichtig zu merken (+1)